# c shell script to check if Git is available in the system

Tags: git, shell, scripting, csh

I am currently creating a script that does some manipulations on the files for our software framework. Now that we have moved to Git, there are some functions that this scripts need to setup (ie: ignore local changes on some files).

So I was thinking of this C shell script to check if Git is installed in the system prior to performing certain Git actions to be backward compatible with other systems without Git installed.

I was thinking of using `which` or `whereis` but i can't seem to integrate it with the C shell `if()` statement.

Comment: Does it have to be a `csh`-specific script? If so, why?

Comment: yes because this is the shell that was chosen by whoever started this old servers... to be honest i can't really give enough reason why. we're just stuck with csh. sorry

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Does torek's answer solve your problem? If so, please upvote/accept it. Otherwise, leave some feedback below torek's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* need csh, this works:

```
if ( -x `which git` ) then
    ... what to do if it can be run ...
else
    ... what to do if it cannot
endif
```

The `-x` test checks whether the given path is executable, and the backquotes run `which` to find the path (or print `git: command not found`, which won't be executable).

As [Carpetsmoker noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453289/c-shell-script-to-check-if-git-is-available-in-the-system/32455655?noredirect=1#comment52775251_32455655), if you are using tcsh (or have a csh that's really just tcsh, as is the case on modern Macs and FreeBSD for instance), you can just use:

```
if ( -X git ) then ...
```

You're much better off with a sane shell, though.

Comment: You can just use `-X` (capital `x`), no need for the `which`: `if ( -X git ) echo "git found"`

Comment: Interesting ... according to the documentation, uppercase X is new in tcsh (vs plain csh).  The man page also has a caveat, do not path-qualify: `-X /bin/ls` is generally false, but that's easily controlled.

Comment: Yeah, it's a `tcsh` think, but AFAIK the amount of systems that have a `csh` that is *not* `tcsh` is very small to nonexistent...

Answer (score 0):

I am not a regular `csh` user but `man csh` says that one needs to check a value of `status` variable after executing a command as it holds a return value of the last command:

```
status The status returned by the last command. If it terminated
       abnormally, then 0200 is added to the status. Built-in
       commands that fail return exit status 1, all other
       built-in commands set status to 0.
```

For example:

```
$ csh
% which git
/usr/bin/git
% echo $status
0
% which non-existing-command
non-existing-command: Command not found.
% echo $status
1
%
```

Knowing that it's easy to write an `if` condition:

```
#!/usr/bin/env csh

which git > /dev/null
if ($status == 0) then
    echo git found
else
    echo git not found. Exiting.
    exit 1
endif
```

Comment: That's a bit of a roundabout way. You don't have to use the value of `status`.

Comment: As I said, I don't use `csh`. What's a better way?

Comment: My remark wasn't specific to `csh`. You could use which `git ...` in the if statement directly. See my answer.

Comment: You can just use `if ( -X exe )` (capital `x`), no need for the `which`: `if ( -X git ) echo "git found"`